# PHP singleton not accessible in a simple class

Tags: php, oop, singleton

First Happy New Year to all.

I'm stuck on a simple case in php and maybe you can lightup my mind here:

I have php page with js script. This script (based on jquery) contains a document ready event function that makes an Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions/DatasourceEmail.php",
    data: param,                   
    dataType: "json",
    dataFilter: function(data, type){ 
        return data;
    },
    error: function(xhj, statut, thrown){
        alert(xhj.responseText);
    },
    success: function(result){
    ...
```

This working well. My problem is on server side. When I instanciate a class, the code doesn't go inside and instanciate, by the way I don't think so. I have a logging function (singleton) which traces on the first call. But not inside the class when I instanciate

```
class testclass
{
    function instance(){
        ApplicationMedSoft::CurrentApplication()->Trace("@@@@ initialisation !!!");
    }
}
```

...

```
ApplicationMedSoft::CurrentApplication()->Trace("@@@@ initialisation !!!");
$flex = new testclass();
```

Result log:

```
    ...
    [23/01/2018 9:06:34] - [SQL] ==> 1 resultat(s)
    [23/01/2018 9:06:34] - @@@@ initialisation !!!  <= First call
    ??? second (inside class??)
```

All my files are correctly included
It's like my singleton is not working is this class, but in some others classes it's working. 
By looking for too much the problem, I thik I can't see it anymore. Help :)

Thanks for reading

Iainh.

Comment: You mean function instance should be invoked when you initialize a new object from this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expecting your class to log something when it's just created you need to call your function `__construct` and not `instance`.  So you class should be something like...

```
class testclass
{
    public function __construct(){
        ApplicationMedSoft::CurrentApplication()->Trace("@@@@ initialisation !!!");
    }
}
```

I would also recommend that you change the class name to `TestClass` as this is more convention.

If you want the class to behave like a singleton class, then you need to do something slightly different...

```
class TestClass
{
    public static function instance(){
        ApplicationMedSoft::CurrentApplication()->Trace("@@@@ initialisation !!!");
    }
}
```

Adding `static` to the method allows you to call it without creating a new object, call it using...

```
$flex = TestClass::instance();
```

Have a read of http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I'll try it. 

Of course my classes are well named. I've just made this one for testing :)
I'll keep you informed 

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something when you make an object of that class here:-

```
$flex = new testclass();
```

echo $flex or return $flex, if its an array and function json_encode to it and then echo or return like:-

```
return json_encode($flex);
```

Third, you need to add exit or die statement after it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Actually I do it later. My logs are written server side by the way. 

    ApplicationMedSoft::CurrentApplication()->Trace("@@@@ initialisation !!!");
    $flex = new testclass();
    echo json_encode($flex);

My problem is when I trace, nothing is traced from inside my class, but outside yes :|